# Hide legend for a single geom in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I map the same variable (color) to color in two different geoms.  I want them either to appear in separate legends (DHJ and EFI) or preferably just skip the second legend (for E, F, and I) altogether.  Currently, R mixes the two together and gives me a legend that lists DEFHIJ in alphabetical order all mixed together.

Basically, I want to graph today's points onto some smoothed lines that use a standard dataset.  I don't want there to be a legend for the smoothed lines - we are all familiar with them and they are standard on all our graphs.  I just want a legend for the points only.

I've tried `show.legend = FALSE` as suggested elsewhere, but that doesn't seem to have an effect.  `guides(color = FALSE)` removes the entire legend.

Reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)

set1 <- diamonds %>%
  filter(color %in% c("D", "H", "J")) 

set2 <- diamonds %>%
  filter(color %in% c("E", "F", "I")) 

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = set1, 
             aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) +
  geom_smooth(data = set2, 
              show.legend = FALSE, 
              aes(x = x, y = y, color = color))
```

Here is the graph that is produced.  It has all 6 letters in the legend, instead of only DHJ.
[image]

Comment: I'm running regular (non-dev) ggplot v2.2.1.  I didn't think show.legend = FALSE was a new feature, though.

Comment: Ah, your edit makes things much clearer.  One option is to show the specific breaks you'd like to show in `scale_x_discrete`: `scale_color_discrete(breaks = set1$color)`.

Comment: @aosmith this is very interesting - I am slightly baffled by the fact that the plot still has six colors and that setting those breaks only affects the legend... Why??

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are trying to do.  If you don't want the lines to be colored you shouldn't map a variable to a color in the `geom_smooth` layer.  If you need separate lines fit to groups then you could instead use the `group` aesthetic (or `linetype`) to get the lines.

Comment: Probably using the diamonds dataset isn't showing this clearly.  We have 5 smooth lines that run on all of our graphs.  We don't need a legend for those - they are universal (sort of background info).  We have various bits of data we plot on top of those lines, and I only want the legend to refer to those.

Comment: @aosmith - your scale_color_discrete(breaks = set1$color) did the trick perfectly.  If you list that as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the legend to show only the colors from one dataset you can do so by setting the `breaks` in `scale_color_discrete()` to those values.

```
... +
     scale_color_discrete(breaks = unique(set1$color) )
```

If you aren't using the colors of the lines, since this is standard background info, you could add the lines by using `group` in`geom_smooth()` instead of `color`.  (Also see `linetype` if you wanted to be able to tell the lines apart.)

```
ggplot() +
     geom_point(data = set1, 
                aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) +
     geom_smooth(data = set2, 
                 aes(x = x, y = y, group = color))
```